# import ics file to google calendar using API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Is there any possible solution for importing an ics file to google calendar using their API. I have refered so many blogs and couldn't find any exact solution for my need. I am working in a node application and creating the ics file using a node module. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calendar API v3 does not support ICS files. You can either parse the ICS file and fill in the API v3 request with the data or you can use CalDAV API which natively supports ICS files but you will need to make sure there is only at maximum one event in each ICS file. The documentation for CalDAV is here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide

Comment: Also worth mentioning: Here's the official issue entry: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=210