# How do i get raw ics (google calendar) file from Google Calendar API

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events, google-calendar-reminders

Here is my example code:

```
String eventId = "XXX";
String calendarId = "YYY";

outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\AAA\\Documents\\notepads\\output-text.ics");     
calendarService.events().get(calendarId, eventId).executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

This is giving a JSON output. I need to convert event into an .ics file, is there any ways to do it..? or do i need to construct it manually..? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to do it yourself Google calendar api responds in Json.

Comment: This question is a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750678/import-ics-file-to-google-calendar-using-api/26820510

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import ics file to google calendar using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750678/import-ics-file-to-google-calendar-using-api)